# Got connection reset error when one node of oracle RAC is taken down for maintenence

Tags: oracle, websphere, oracle-rac

I have an Oracle DB RAC setup of 2 servers and config SCAN hostname pointing to both servers. My Websphere application server config with jdbc string like below and connection pool of 50:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//scan-hostname:port/dbname
```

Everything works fine and both db servers are getting request as expected, except that when either node is down (and the other node is normal), my application will get all kinds of exceptions like (connection reset/JDBC commit failed/Connection is closed) just within first several minutes and normal afterwards.

My guess is those pooled connections to the failing node does not do any retry or failover and just throw exceptions. Is it expected behavior for oracle RAC, that failover only working for new connections not existing connections, or am I missing something somewhere to enable failover?

Comment: [This might be useful](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/tdat_oraclerac.html) - particularly the bits about failover and ONS (and connection caching).

Comment: Are you using WebSphere's connection pooling or Oracle's Universal Connection Pool (UCP)?  If you want to take advantage of Oracle's automated features such as ONS you'll need to use UCP.